Tooltip gets hidden in Mantine-React-Table
I have a standard Mantine React Table  and I want to add a tooltip to on of the Action Icons and the column headers. However, when I do, they are cut-off by the length of the column. How can I make the tooltip the highest priority? I have tried using the z-index to no avail.
This is my table:

const table = useMantineReactTable({
...
renderRowActions: ({ row }) => (
        <>
        <Tooltip label="Text" position="left" withArrow z-index="9999">
        <Box style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', gap: '0px' }}>
          <ActionIcon onClick={(event) => handleViewJSON()}>
            
              <IconJson />
   
          </ActionIcon>
        </Box>
        </Tooltip>
    ),
    ...
}


you can try the withinPortal prop on the tooltip to force it.
